# Jquery scroll to class with previous and next buttons, multiple elements

Tags: jquery, class, scroll, click

I have a jquery script which scrolls to certain element with given class on click of button.

I've made it so when you click on button "next" it scrolls to first element with class "highlight" which is located within a long text.

My true need is to set up or upgrade that script so you could navigate from element to element with same classes on clicking to "previous" and "next" buttons.
So far I have this script which only scrolls to first element with given class and prev and next button from which only next button is functionable.

Is something like that even possible to make with so simple script? or I need to use some other plugin.

Here is my situation till now  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/3JQp5/).

In html there is a lot of text, you can view it on link for jsfiddle... here I will replace it with "..." :

```
<div class="navigation">
   <a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a>
   <br>
   <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="demo-container">
   <p>
      ...
      <span class="highlight">ipsum</span> 
      ...
      <span class="highlight">Duis</span> 
      ...
      <span class="highlight">convallis</span> 
      ...
      <span class="highlight">blandit</span>
      ...
      <span class="highlight">Sed</span>
      ....
   </p>
</div>
```

script:

```
/**  scroll to element function **/
function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
    time = typeof (time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
    verticalOffset = typeof (verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $(selector);
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, time);
}

/**document ready**/
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* scroll to -150px before .highlight with animation time of 1000ms */
    $('#next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollToElement('.highlight', 1000, -150);
    });
});
```

css:

```
.highlight{
  background-color:red;
}

.navigation{
     position:fixed;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     padding:5px;
     border: 1px solid;
}
```

you can edit my jsfiddle freely.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a simple counter like this, and use the [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
var count = 0;
$('#next').click(function (e) {
    count++;
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollToElement('.highlight:nth-child(' + count + ')', 1000, -150);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

To add some dynamism to this, (since you wouldn't know how many `.highlight` elements will be there).. You could do something like this,

```
count = 0;
var max_length = $('.highlight').length;

$('#next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (count < max_length) {
        count++;
    } 
    else {
        count = 1;
        alert("reached start point");
    }

    scrollToElement('.highlight:nth-child(' + count + ')', 1000, -150);
    .
    .
    .
```

**UPDATE:**

Well, in that case, I'd tell you to handle the click event in a different way, instead of having 2 separate methods, you could have one method that does the job,

So, your `.click()` would look like,

```
$('.navigation a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    if(id === "next"){
         if (count < max_length) {
            count++;
         } else {
            count = 1;
            alert("reached start point");
         }
    }
    else{
         if (count > 1) {
            count--;
         } else {
            count = max_length;
            alert("reached start point");
         }            
    }
    scrollToElement('.highlight:nth-child(' + count + ')', 1000, -150);
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3JQp5/1/)

[Test Link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3JQp5/2/)

[Test Link 3](http://jsfiddle.net/3JQp5/3/)

Comment: ohh! that's great man! But what about 'previous' button? How can it be programmed to scroll back to previous element from position where are you now after clicking 'next'

Comment: Updated my answer, please have a look

Comment: thanks man! love you solution, I've managed to work it out too on a little bit different way but similar... have a look http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/xemGE/

Comment: @painotpi do you have an idea how to use that in a horizontal slider like this: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/eYdojOg